# How to implement error output during validation for each field separately?

Tags: java, html, angularjs

I'm doing backend validation in Java and return in AngularJS error info after validation. How can I display errors for each checked field separately?

Main.js - file with AngularJS

```
var app = angular.module('myShoppingList', ['ngRoute','ngStorage', 'ngMessages']);

//some code

$scope.listCustomers;

        $scope.postFunc = function(){

          if ($scope.formCust) {
                $scope.listCustomers =this.formCust;
                $scope.formCust = {};
              }

            var urlInfo = "/save";

            var config = {
                        headers : {
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                          'Accept': 'application/json'
                        }
                }

            var dataArr = $scope.listCustomers;

            $http.post(urlInfo, dataArr, config).then(function (response) {

              $scope.postDivAvailable = true;

              $scope.postCust =  response.data;

            }, function error(response) {
              $scope.postResultMessage = response.data;

            });

            $scope.listCustomers = [];
            $scope.result = 'Success!';
          }
});
```

shipping.html - html file with input form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app='myShoppingList' ng-cloak="">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.11/ngStorage.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>

<title>Shipping Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Shipping information</h1>

  <form ng-submit="postFunc()" ng-controller="myCtrl">

          <table>

          <tr>
          <td><label for="firstName">First name:</label><td>
          <td><input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name" ng-model="formCust.firstName" required/><td>
          <tr>

          <tr>
          <td><label for="phoneNumber">Phone number:</label><td>
          <td><input type="text" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="Enter phone number" ng-model="formCust.phoneNumber" required/><td>
          <tr>

          <tr>
          <td><label for="cardNumber">Card number:</label><td>
          <td><input type="text" id="cardNumber" placeholder="Enter card number" ng-model="formCust.cardNumber" required/><td>
          <tr>

          </table>

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>  {{postResultMessage}}

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Now my response looks like this:
[image]

How i can put each error info near the corresponding field?

Answer (score 1):

For backend validation of the form fields , the best option is to go for **Schema Validation**

First create your schema that will validate all fields of the object and store this in your class path of backend code.

**schema.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Product",
    "description": "A product from the catalog",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "description": "The first name of the user",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "phoneNumber": {
            "description": "Phone number of the user",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "cardNumber": {
            "description": "Card number of the user",
            "type": "string",

        }
    },
    "required": ["firstName", "phoneNumber", "cardNumber"]
}
```

dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.everit.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.everit.json.schema</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This can be used in the Validator class in Java

```
    JSONObject jsonSchema = new JSONObject( new 
    JSONTokener(JSONSchemaTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/schema.json")));

    JSONObject jsonSubject = new JSONObject(userObject);

    Schema schema = SchemaLoader.load(jsonSchema);
    schema.validate(jsonSubject);
```

This will validate entire object and return exception if any field is invalid . you can return that exception to Angular JS code from java.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , **give your form a name** so that it can be checked whether form is submitted or not .

Then **span tag can be used within each  block for each field** as given in the following code .

If **form is submiited and any required field is missing** then the correcsponsing error message will be shown near the respective field .

```
 <form name="myForm" ng-submit="postFunc()" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <table>

          <tr>
              <td><label for="firstName">First name:</label>
              <td>
              <td><input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name" ng-model="formCust.firstName" required />
              <td>
                  <span ng-if="myForm.$submitted && !formCust.firstName">First Name is required to be filled up.
                  </span>
          <tr>

          <tr>
              <td><label for="phoneNumber">Phone number:</label>
              <td>
              <td><input type="text" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="Enter phone number" ng-model="formCust.phoneNumber" required />
              <td>
                  <span ng-if="myForm.$submitted && !formCust.phoneNumber">Phone Number is required to be filled up.
                  </span>
          <tr>

          <tr>
              <td><label for="cardNumber">Card number:</label>
              <td>
              <td><input type="text" id="cardNumber" placeholder="Enter card number" ng-model="formCust.cardNumber" required />
              <td>
                  <span ng-if="myForm.$submitted && !formCust.cardNumber">Card Number is required to be filled up.
                  </span>
          <tr>

      </table>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button> {{postResultMessage}}

  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not with backend validation :\

Comment: Sorry , I missed that backend validation part .Posting another answer for that .